# how to display modal view in 5 second?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I am doing a modal view controller (changeviewcontroller) that will be appeared just 5 seconds , so how to do that ? what are the important codes i need to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
create a method in you modalview controller class to dismiss  modal view controllr.

```
-(void)dismissModal{
   [self dissmissModalViewController];
}
```

Call this method with a delay of 5 seconds, from your viewdidLoad method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [self performSelector @selector(dismissModal) afterDelay:5.0 ];

}
```

check the syntax, i am not using xcode .

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method:

```
-(void)someButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
   [self performSelector:@selector(openController) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)openController
{
    //present the view controller
    SomeViewController *ctrl = ....;
    [self present...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in to the NSTimer class. Set it to run 5 seconds and invoke a selecor to dismiss the view. It's all in the Apple Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:5

 animations:^{ 
   //add you modal view here
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(theSelector) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This should do it. Just insert the right selector.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC(Model View Controller)

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
                 [self performSelector:@selector(CloseViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

}

    -(void)CloseViewController{

        [yourViewController dissmissModalViewController];
    }
```

if you use here any view then its also work pretty like bellow

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [self performSelector:@selector(hideView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
-(void)hideView{

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[yourView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
    yourView.hidden=YES;
}
```

in above i use Imageview Insted of MVC.
I hope its useful for you...
:)